# SQL count TIMESTAMPDIFF values, ordered by day entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I`m having a hard time finding the right query, please help.
Explanations: I have a table where rows are inserted based on login status. 
The table looks like this (part of it):

```
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| username | view_start | view_stop | action  |     action_time     |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| adrian   | 10:00:00   |           | log-in  | 2015-09-01/10:00:00 |
| adrian   | 10:00:00   | 10:35:00  | log-off | 2015-09-01/10:35:00 |
| john     | 12:00:00   |           | log-in  | 2015-09-01/12:00:00 |
| john     | 12:00:00   | 12:45:00  | log-off | 2015-09-01/12:45:00 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

I want to achieve the following things:

- count the differences between `view_start` and `view_stop` for the rows that have the action `log-off` (the last action they did)
- order that list based on day time (total time the users were logged-in that day)

What I achieved till now:

I counted and ordered total users based by day

```
SELECT DATE(action_time) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT username) totalCOunt
FROM audit_data
GROUP BY DATE(action_time)
```

Output:

```
+------------+------------+
|    date    | totalCOunt |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-09-01 |          5 |
| 2015-09-02 |          3 |
| 2015-09-03 |          1 |
| 2015-09-04 |          7 |
+------------+------------+
```

I calculated the difference between the two dates

```
SELECT view_start, view_stop,username, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, view_start, view_stop) AS MinuteDiff 
FROM audit_data 
WHERE action = "off-line" 
ORDER BY username

+------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| view_start | view_stop | username | MinuteDiff |
+------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 10:00:00   | 11:00:00  | adrian   |         60 |
| 11:00:00   | 12:00:00  | adrian   |         60 |
| 12:00:00   | 13:00:00  | john     |         60 |
| 13:00:00   | 14:00:00  | george   |         60 |
+------------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I want to "combine" these queries to calculate the total time that users were logged-in, per days:

```
+-------------+---------------------+
|     day     | totalDiff (minutes) |
+-------------+---------------------+
| 2015-09-01  |                 120 |
| 2015-09-02  |                  38 |
| 2015-09-03  |                  76 |
| 2015-09-04  |                 156 |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

Important detail: A user can login multiple times a day

The query that I tried:
`SELECT DATE(action_time) Date, COUNT(SELECT SUM(SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, view_start, view_stop) )) totalCOunt FROM audit_data GROUP BY DATE(action_time)`

Comment: What if a user is logged on over midnight?

Comment: Smart question...I guess it will be counted for the next day. The data doesn't need to be extremly precise

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `action = "off-line"`  is non-standard SQL

Comment: mysql. it's just a varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description you simply need to sum the minutes:

```
SELECT DATE(action_time) Date 
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT username) totalCOunt 
   ,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, view_start, view_stop)) AS totalDiff 
FROM audit_data 
GROUP BY DATE(action_time)
ORDER BY 1
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6aa91/2)

Comment: I already tried that and it gives me an error (probably the query is not well writen) `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(DISTINCT username) totalCOunt 
   ,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, view_start, v' at line 2 `

Comment: The query that I tried : `SELECT DATE(action_time) Date, COUNT(SELECT SUM(SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, view_start, view_stop) )) totalCOunt FROM audit_data GROUP BY DATE(action_time)`. It gives me the same error

Comment: @Adrian: I just checked it and it works fine on Fiddle (see edit), must be something else.

Comment: Silly me, it was a spelling mistake. Thanks for the query, it works as expected